# how find rows where a particular column has decimal numbers using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-quality

I am writing a data quality script using pandas, where the script would be checking certain conditions on each column

At the moment i need to find out the rows that don't have a decimal or an actual number in a a particular column. I am able to find the numbers if its a whole number, but the methods I have seen so far ie `isdigit() , isnumeric(), isdecimal()` etc fail to correctly identify when the number is a decimal number. eg: 2.5, 0.1245 etc.

Following is some sample code & data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([
    [np.nan, 'foo', 0],
    [1, '', 1],
    [-1.387326, np.nan, 2],
    [0.814772, ' baz', ' '],     
    ["a", '      ', 4],
    ["  ",  'foo qux ', '  '],         
], columns='A B C'.split(),dtype=str)

>>> df
    A   B   C
0   NaN foo 0
1   1       1
2   -1.387326   NaN 2
3   0.814772    baz 
4   a       4
5       foo qux 

>>> df['A']
0          NaN
1            1
2    -1.387326
3     0.814772
4            a
5             
Name: A, dtype: object
```

The following method all fails to identify the decimal numbers

```
df['A'].fillna('').str.isdigit()
df['A'].fillna('').str.isnumeric()
df['A'].fillna('').str.isdecimal()

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

So when i try the following I only get 1 row

```
>>> df[df['A'].fillna('').str.isdecimal()]
    A   B   C
1   1       1
```

NB: I am using `dtype=str` to get the data wihtout pandas interpreting/changing the values of the dtypes. The actual data could have spaces in column A, I will trim that out using replace(), I have kept the code simple here so as not to confuse things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for non numeric to `NaN`s and then test by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').notna())
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

If need return `True`s for missing values:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').notna() | df['A'].isna())
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Another solution with custom function:

```
def test_numeric(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

print (df['A'].apply(test_numeric))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

print (df['A'].fillna('').apply(test_numeric))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternativ, if you want to keep the string structure you can use:

```
df['A'].str.contains('.')

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

The only risk in that case could be that you identify words with `.`as well..which is not your wish